# restrictions in JSF viewScope

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Please have a look at the code below. The function generateCoupon is never invoked. 
processCouponGeneration and userPageBacking are in viewScope, but headerBacking is in requestScope. tried changing primefaces p:commandButton to h:commandButton, but it does not work.
Using c:set if I copy the headerBacking.currentUser to a viewScoped variable; use this variable instead of headerBacking.currentUser, the function generateCoupon is fired. So, wanted to confirm if this is an expected behavior. These are the problems troubling me a lot in JSF and I do not know if that can be debugged.

```
  <p:commandButton value="Correct"
    action="#{processCouponGeneration.generateCoupon}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener
        target="#{processCouponGeneration.bpd}"
        value="#{userPageBacking.selectedPromoToDisplay.wupdBrandpromo}" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener
        target="#{processCouponGeneration.bpdd}"
        value="#{bpddVar}" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener
        target="#{processCouponGeneration.promoter}"
        value="#{userPageBacking.user}" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener
        target="#{processCouponGeneration.buyer}"
        value="#{headerBacking.currentUser}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Make sure you have all the getters and setters in all of you managed beans.

Comment: Any missing getters/setters would have produced clear and self-describing EL exceptions instead of "doing nothing".

Comment: But, I don't think it's any ViewScope issue becuase I tried it and the method is being called.

Comment: That's correct. The question is plain unanswerable without further detail from the OP. That's why nobody answered it until now ;) It's only far beyond me why the question got 2 upvotes.

Comment: True!... No managed bean code at all. Without all of that I think all a reader can do is guess.